# I can't get jQuery plugin AnythingSlider to work in JS Bin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a jQuery plugin to a website I am working on for one of my coding classes. (see code at https://jsbin.com/jawibotera/edit?html,output) I am trying to add the plugin AnythingSlider to my code. I am following the documentation on the Github wiki page (https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Setup) especially for the code in the head tags and the example HTML. However the output always shows the three pictures underneath each other and aren't in a slide show. So far I've changed the css pages and have made sure I have set everything to jQuery. I removed all the optional plugins and used all the links provided from my coding course. For the assignment, I was given these links:

http://skillcrush.com/wp-content/themes/skillcrush2.30/class-files/anything-slider/js/jquery.anythingslider.min.js

http://skillcrush.com/wp-content/themes/skillcrush2.30/class-files/anything-slider/css/anythingslider.css

Even when I use the links my coding course provides, I am not able to get a slideshow. I looked at the code for the examples on the Github page to double check my own code, however I can't find any errors. Should I link two css pages to one site? If not, which css page should I use?

Comment: can I please recommend flexslider by WooThemes? It's free and awesome and extremely customisable. I will look at your case now, but the most popular slider (and therefore the best support) is FlexSlider.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I was using anythingslider since it was one suggested by my course. I use FlexSlider from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really recommend that you go with flexslider, as it is far superior to this in my opinion, and I don't know what was wrong with your implementation but when moving your site on top of a JSFiddle with anythingslider already in it, it worked just fine. Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/10706/

and since the only thing I changed was the Jquery here it is too:

```
var modalContainer = $("#modal-container");

var hideModal = function() {
  modalContainer.hide();
};

var showModal = function() {
  modalContainer.show();
};

var modalShowButton = $("#modal-show");
modalShowButton.on("click", showModal);

var modalCloseButton = $("modal-hide");
modalCloseButton.on("click", hideModal);

$(document).on("keyup", function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;

  if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
    hideModal();
  }
});

var handleNewsletterSignup = function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  var newsletterHeader = $("#newsletter-header");

  var newsletterForm = $("#newsletter-signup");
  newsletterForm.hide();

  newsletterHeader.text("Thank you for signing up!");

  setTimeout(hideModal, 2000);
};

var newsletterForm = $("#newsletter-signup");
newsletterForm.on("submit", handleNewsletterSignup);

var clockTime = function() {
  var currentTime = new Date ();

  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

  if (hours <= 11) {
    var period = "AM";
  } else {
    var period = "PM";
  }

  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
  } else if (hours === 0) {
    hours = 12;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + String(minutes);
  }

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + String(seconds);
  }

  var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + period;

  return time;
};

var clock = $("#clock");

setInterval(function() {
  clock.text(clockTime());
}, 1000);




$('#slider').anythingSlider({

    // *********** Appearance ***********
    // Theme name; choose from: minimalist-round, minimalist-square,
    // metallic, construction, cs-portfolio
    theme: 'default',
    // Set mode to "horizontal", "vertical" or "fade"
    // (only first letter needed); replaces vertical option
    mode: 'horizontal',
    // If true, the entire slider will expand to fit the parent element
    expand: false,
    // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to
    // fit the viewport
    resizeContents: true,
    // Set this value to a number and it will show that many slides at once
    showMultiple: false,
    // Anything other than "linear" or "swing" requires the easing plugin
    easing: "swing",

    // If true, builds the forwards and backwards buttons
    buildArrows: true,
    // If true, builds a list of anchor links to link to each panel
    buildNavigation: true,
    // If true, builds the start/stop button
    buildStartStop: true,

    // Append forward arrow to a HTML element
    // (jQuery Object, selector or HTMLNode), if not null
    appendFowardTo: null,
    // Append back arrow to a HTML element
    // (jQuery Object, selector or HTMLNode), if not null
    appendBackTo: null,
    // Append controls (navigation + start-stop) to a HTML element
    // (jQuery Object, selector or HTMLNode), if not null
    appendControlsTo: null,
    // Append navigation buttons to a HTML element
    // (jQuery Object, selector or HTMLNode), if not null
    appendNavigationTo: null,
    // Append start-stop button to a HTML element
    // (jQuery Object, selector or HTMLNode), if not null
    appendStartStopTo: null,

    // If true, side navigation arrows will slide out on
    // hovering & hide @ other times
    toggleArrows: false,
    // if true, slide in controls (navigation + play/stop button)
    // on hover and slide change, hide @ other times
    toggleControls: false,

    // Start button text
    startText: "Start",
    // Stop button text
    stopText: "Stop",
    // Link text used to move the slider forward
    // (hidden by CSS, replaced with arrow image)
    forwardText: "&raquo;",
    // Link text used to move the slider back
    // (hidden by CSS, replace with arrow image)
    backText: "&laquo;",
    // Class added to navigation & start/stop button
    // (text copied to title if it is hidden by a negative text indent)
    tooltipClass: 'tooltip',

    // if false, arrows will be visible, but not clickable.
    enableArrows: true,
    // if false, navigation links will still be visible, but not clickable.
    enableNavigation: true,
    // if false, the play/stop button will still be visible, but not
    // clickable. Previously "enablePlay"
    enableStartStop: true,
    // if false, keyboard arrow keys will not work for this slider.
    enableKeyboard: true,

    // *********** Navigation ***********
    // This sets the initial panel
    startPanel: 1,
    // Amount to go forward or back when changing panels.
    changeBy: 1,
    // Should links change the hashtag in the URL?
    hashTags: true,
    // if false, the slider will not wrap
    infiniteSlides: true,
    // Details at the top of the file on this use (advanced use)
    navigationFormatter: function(index, panel) {
        // This is the default format (show just the panel index number)
        return "" + index;
    },
    // Set this to the maximum number of visible navigation tabs;
    // false to disable
    navigationSize: false,

    // *********** Slideshow options ***********
    // If true, the slideshow will start running; replaces "startStopped" option
    autoPlay: false,
    // If true, user changing slides will not stop the slideshow
    autoPlayLocked: false,
    // If true, starting a slideshow will delay advancing slides; if false, the slider will immediately advance to the next slide when slideshow starts
    autoPlayDelayed: false,
    // If true & the slideshow is active, the slideshow will pause on hover
    pauseOnHover: true,
    // If true & the slideshow is active, the  slideshow will stop on the last page. This also stops the rewind effect  when infiniteSlides is false.
    stopAtEnd: false,
    // If true, the slideshow will move right-to-left
    playRtl: false,

    // *********** Times ***********
    // How long between slideshow transitions in AutoPlay mode (in milliseconds)
    delay: 3000,
    // Resume slideshow after user interaction, only if autoplayLocked is true (in milliseconds).
    resumeDelay: 15000,
    // How long the slideshow transition takes (in milliseconds)
    animationTime: 600,
    // How long to pause slide animation before going to the desired slide (used if you want your "out" FX to show).
    delayBeforeAnimate  : 0,

    // *********** Callbacks ***********
    // Callback before the plugin initializes
    onBeforeInitialize: function(e, slider) {},
    // Callback when the plugin finished initializing
    onInitialized: function(e, slider) {},
    // Callback on slideshow start
    onShowStart: function(e, slider) {},
    // Callback after slideshow stops
    onShowStop: function(e, slider) {},
    // Callback when slideshow pauses
    onShowPause: function(e, slider) {},
    // Callback when slideshow unpauses - may not trigger
    // properly if user clicks on any controls
    onShowUnpause: function(e, slider) {},
    // Callback when slide initiates, before control animation
    onSlideInit: function(e, slider) {},
    // Callback before slide animates
    onSlideBegin: function(e, slider) {},
    // Callback when slide completes - no event variable!
    onSlideComplete: function(slider) {},
    // Callback when slider resizes
    onSliderResize: function(e, slider) {},

    // *********** Interactivity ***********
    // Event used to activate forward arrow functionality
    // (e.g. add jQuery mobile's "swiperight")
    clickForwardArrow: "click",
    // Event used to activate back arrow functionality
    // (e.g. add jQuery mobile's "swipeleft")
    clickBackArrow: "click",
    // Events used to activate navigation control functionality
    clickControls: "click focusin",
    // Event used to activate slideshow play/stop button
    clickSlideshow: "click",

    // *********** Video ***********
    // If true & the slideshow is active & a youtube video
    // is playing, it will pause the autoplay until the video
    // is complete
    resumeOnVideoEnd: true,
    // If true the video will resume playing (if previously
    // paused, except for YouTube iframe - known issue);
    // if false, the video remains paused.
    resumeOnVisible: true,
    // If your slider has an embedded object, the script will
    // automatically add a wmode parameter with this setting
    addWmodeToObject: "opaque",
    // return true if video is playing or false if not - used
    // by video extension
    isVideoPlaying: function(base) {
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I looked at your code. I think the problem was js Bin. I put the code in codepen and I got it to work.